# How to export existing GCP cloud infrastructure to terraform code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

After searching I found that I can use [Terraforming Tool](https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming), for exporting AWS cloud infra to terraform code.

How to export my existing Google cloud infrastructure to terraform? Are there any similar or native tools for GCP?

Comment: As of 2022, GCP provides a beta feature to do this. Please check   https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/export

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a tool for converting existing GCP resources to terraform code known as Terraformer.

Here is the link for it

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer

Video demo link: https://asciinema.org/a/243961

Comment: that's exactly it ! have you used it ? any problems or smth to look out for or works nicely ?

Comment: Personally haven't tried it.. You can have a look at demo video thats works cool